# need to parse a string as mm:ss not as hh:mm

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I need to convert a `string` values that are `mm:ss` (examples - `"6:12"`, `"59:59"`, `"6:6"`) and sum them up that are in `hh:mm:ss` formatted value.

At the moment i'm trying to do a simple thing, but it is *throwing me this exception*:

> "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'"

Here's the example of the code:

```
string time = "6:14";
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "mm:ss", null);
string total = ts.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have **2** issues with your code:

1. You use *custom separator* `:` which should be *escaped* with `\`
2. You don't use *leading zeroes* (`"06:14"`), that's why you should put `m` instead of `mm` (and `s` instead of `ss` if `"6:6"` is a correct value):

**Code:**

```
  string time = "6:14";
  TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, @"m\:s", null);
  string total = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Comment: Thank you for not only solving this case but also explaining me why.

Comment: @xanatos: it should be `hh`, not `HH` since we apply formatting on `TimeSpan` (some interval, just number of hours), not `DateTime` where 24h / 12h make sence